# How to update loop?

Tags: python

I have string like this

```
txt = 'hi how are you user alex12 ?'
```

and I need to make some changes like this

```
 col1          |  col2
 --------------|------------
'hi'           |  'H1'
'are you'      |  'B1'
'user alex12'  |  'A1 B2 C1'
```

I want this result

```
txt = 'H1 how B1 A1 B2 C1 ?'
```

and this is the hard part, the `col1` is a `list` of `1,000` item's, I made this code but it's not work well

```
check_list = ['hi', 'are you', ...]
temp = txt.split()
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if temp in check_list:
        temp[i] = check_list[check_list.index(temp[i])
```

Comment: Do you want to replace "hi" by "HI", "re you" by "B1" and "some changes" by "A1 B2" in a string?

Comment: @zabop yes I update the code and add more code

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra I added more code

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
txt = 'hi how are you user alex12 ?'

check_list = ["hi", "are you", "user alex12"]
replace_to = ["H1","B1","A1 B2 C1"]
```

You can do:

```
for c, r in zip(check_list,replace_to):
    txt = txt.replace(c,r)
```

`txt` will be:

```
H1 how B1 A1 B2 C1 ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split like you did you will never get your second row, you need to go about it the other way, go over the first column and search it in your text.

Answer (score 0):

So what i got from your question according to that
this solution should be enough

```
txt = 'hi how are you user alex12 ?'
col1 = ["hi","are you","user alex12"]
col2 = ['H1','B1','A1 B1 C1']
for i in range(0,len(col1)):
    txt = txt.replace(col1[i],col2[i])

print(txt)
```